# C++ Client using libcurl to upload files to EFT Servers

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

I have currently been handling a project which was not originally built by me. It is a client connecting to a EFT server and need to upload files at a click of a button. As when the software was being built we did not have the credentials it was built to test locally on an Apache server.

The GUI is built using Visual C# and the service using libcurl and C++.

There was a file called fileCurl.cpp and I added the credentials in the _startUpload class

```
// What URL that receives this POST 
curl_easy_setopt(cFileCurl->mCurl, CURLOPT_URL, sUrl.c_str());
//Username and Password
curl_easy_setopt(cFileCurl->mCurl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myname:thesecret");
```

The GUI is parsed using JSON and the host and port is got. Even after this the Server returns 401 (user authentication error).

I need some leads into this and if any information I have left do let me know and I will post it immediately.

Thanks

Comment: Because I don't know: What is EFT?

Comment: I am sorry..it is a web server, a commercial online server.

Answer (score 0):

The response headers you got with the 401 contains the info you need, like for example which HTTP authentication methods the server supports for this URL. Your libcurl options there seems to use the default method only which is Basic.